# `imap` conditional to white space left of cursor

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have the following command be in effect

```
imap <Tab> <C-N>
```

**unless** the character left of the cursor is a white space, in which case, `<Tab>` should be `<Tab>`
*(or as an interesting variant, **unless** the text left of the cursor matches `^\s*$`, where `$` stands for the end of the string left of the cursor)* ?

**Edit : solution**

Thanks to the link provided by @[Meninx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392605/meninx)

I found the following snippet in the vim Help

```
function! CleverTab()
   if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
      return "\<Tab>"
   else
      return "\<C-N>"
   endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=CleverTab()<CR>
```

which precisely implements what I wanted.

Comment: You can check this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_mapping_for_tab_completion) and from it you can build a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `<C-R>=` in the `inoremap`.  It is wiser to use an `<expr>` argument to `inoremap`, it will evaluate the last argument as an expression and then substitute the result.  In your example it would look as follows:

```
function! CleverTab()
   if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
      return "\<Tab>"
   else
      return "\<c-x>\<c-p>"
   endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <tab> CleverTab()
```

Most `inoremap` maps are performed with `<expr>`, otherwise things become too complex too quickly.

Note that I also changed `<C-N>` to `<c-x><c-p>`.  In most cases a context sensitive completion will find a better match looking backward than forward, since you are using it to repeat some text.

Also, we have a Vim specific part of the website: https://vi.stackexchange.com/